# Design for massive dimensional table to improve query time? Can it be partitioned horizontally?

Tags: partitioning, normalization

I've never had this issue before -- but inheriting a big data project.

There is a dimensional table "account" or "user" that contains every dimensions known to mankind. Or let's say 400 dimensions. Height, weight, zodiac, favorite quadriped.

It's in snowflake with 'indexes under the hood' (still figuring that out) - but the table is generated by an extremely complicated query one -- and the table is slow to load, two.

I've heard of row partitioning -- handled differently based on underlying db stack -- but I suppose the first idea would be to partition this table vertically (by field/ column) -- maybe based on query usage stats? (which fields are commonly queried, which aren't) -- and maybe based on column size to an extent (or size to usage ratio)?

Don't want to overthink this, but definitely a godzilla table --- more horizontally than vertically (maybe only a few million records). Any optimizations/ design practices?